# Does $X_n\xrightarrow[]{a.s.} a$ and $Z$ is continuous imply $P(X_n<Z<a)\to 0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

We have a sequence of random variables $X_n\xrightarrow[]{a.s.} a$, where $a$ is a constant, and a continuous random variable $Z$.  Can we prove $P(X_n<Z<a)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$? $X_n$ and $Z$ are not independent here, we may say their joint PDF is $f_n(x,z)$.

If we cannot prove this, can I add some other conditions so that $P(X_n<Z<a)\to 0$ becomes true?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/721644), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Then
$$\{X_n<Z<a\} \subseteq \{a-\epsilon \leq Z \leq a\}  \cup \{X_n\leq a-\epsilon\} $$ So $$P[X_n<Z<a] \leq P[a-\epsilon \leq Z \leq a] + P[X_n\leq a-\epsilon]$$
So if $X_n\rightarrow a$ with prob 1 we get
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X_n<Z<a] \leq P[a-\epsilon \leq Z \leq a] $$
Taking $\epsilon\searrow 0$ and assuming $Z$ has a continuous CDF gives
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[X_n<Z<a] = 0$$

Comment: In retrospect, tightening my first inclusion to $$\{X_n<Z<a\} \subseteq \{a-\epsilon \leq Z < a\} \cup \{X_n\leq a-\epsilon\}$$ and repeating the proof would remove the need for $Z$ to have a continuous CDF (as first pointed out in the answer of Snoop) since $P[a-\epsilon\leq Z < a]\searrow P[\phi]=0$ as $\epsilon \searrow 0$.